# Selecting empty/repeated divs on jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, css, jsoup

I need to extract some values from HTML, but I am having some issues. I will now try to explain what is wrong. This is the related part of source HTML:

```
<div class="selections">
    <div class="selected">
    <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="selected">
    <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="selected">
    <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="selected">
    <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="selected">
    <span>A</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

What I need to do is to detect the number of selected divs. In this case, div # 1,4,5,7,9 are selected. However when I do the following code, it detects only 1 of the selected div and the order of it is lost.

```
Elements skills = doc.select("div.selections");
Elements selections = skills.select("div.selected");
Log.e("Logs",selections.toString());
```

Result:

```
09-25 04:43:41.838  26936-26936/com.testapp E/Logs﹕ <div class="selected">
<span>A</span>
</div>
```

So how can I extract the 1,4,5,7,9 numbers from the given HTML?

Answer (score 1):

```
I'm using jSoup 1.8.3..
I've added ids to your span tags to identify each one of them...just for testing the outcome.

<div class='selections'> 
<div class='selected'> 
<span id='1'>A</span> 
</div> 
<div class=''> 
<span id='2'></span> 
</div> 
<div class=''> 
<span id='3'></span> 
</div> 
<div class='selected'> 
<span id='4'>A</span> 
</div> 
<div class='selected'> 
<span id='5'>A</span> 
</div> 
<div class=''> 
<span id='6'></span> 
</div> 
<div class='selected'> 
<span id='7'>A</span> 
</div> 
<div class=''> 
<span id='8'></span> 
</div> 
<div class='selected'> 
<span id='9'>A</span> 
</div> 
</div>


Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("selections");
for (Element elem : elements) {
Elements e = elem.select("div.selected");
Log.i("Log", e.html());//this is what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For extract all elements

```
  for (Element selection : selections) {
       Log.e("Logs",selection.toString());
       // Log.e("Logs",selection.text()); it return all text in element
  }
```

Hope this help.